# React map object{Arrays}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, как вывести отдельные `<div>` через map() object{arrays} на скриншоте результат console.log().

My code:

```
Object.values(BiblInfo).map((arr, i) =>{
 return <li key ={i}>{arr[1]}</li>
 })
```

Когда я использую:
`return(<li key={i}>{arr}<li>)`- все массивы объединяются, но необходимо, чтобы в отдельных `<div>` было записано.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

`{arr}` это такой же массив, вот и пройдитесь по нему итерацией и выводите в `<div>` каждый элемент.